# Virtualbox VM only getting IPv6 over bridge connection. How to get IPv4 address

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, wifi, virtualbox

I have launched Ubuntu16.04 in Oracle virtual box on windows 10 machine. I have used two type of adapters: NAT and Bridge Connection. The ip address on Bridge connection is getting IPv6 address and not IPv4. I have already tried updating preference in /etc/gai.conf file. But this change is not making any difference. Not sure what is happening.

I am connecting over (home or office) wifi.

This is what i am getting when i do `ifconfig`

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9f:b2:ae  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d279:a2f3:ceec:7c63/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:930 (930.0 B)  TX bytes:6645 (6.6 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f1:ae:d5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1bc:78a1:8d5e:90ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1083 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:4363 (4.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2386 (2.3 KB)  TX bytes:2386 (2.3 KB)
```

However, strange part is when i connect over wifi on mobile tethering, i am getting IPv4 for enp0s8

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9f:b2:ae  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d279:a2f3:ceec:7c63/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1919 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:7121 (7.1 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f1:ae:d5  
          inet addr:192.168.43.175  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1bc:78a1:8d5e:90ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2751 (2.7 KB)  TX bytes:6492 (6.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3402 (3.4 KB)  TX bytes:3402 (3.4 KB)
```

Please suggest how can i get IPv4 over Wifi connection.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old but I figured it might help someone else out there...

I also faced the same issue just now. What I did to fix it was to switch to NAT mode in the server settings and then restart networking on the virtual machine. `service networking restart`  and the just check if it you got a IPv4 address from Virtualbox.

After checking just go into the settings again and switch back to the bridged connection and restart your network on the VM --> `service networking restart`

Not sure why but this solved the issue for me.

Comment: My god.. This does work.. Sounds like a weird workaround, but it solved the problem.. Virtualbox should really look into this issue..

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me when I change my host connection from Wifi to wired, But I was still using WiFi settings in VirtualBox adapter, I solved this changing the VirtualBox adapter for the name of my wired adapter.

[image: VirtualBox Connections]